# How to iterate over object that has multiple nested dictionaries?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm struggling to iterate over element that is type "object" which contains nested (unlimited) dictionaries inside dictionaries.

I do have a dictionary that depends on the input data file which (that has various number of columns) which is nested in multiple levels.

Sometimes my dictionary is:

```
{a: {b: {c: [..]}}}
```

And sometimes it could be:

```
{a: {b: [...]}}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to iterate over infinite nested dictionaries inside dictionaries.
I don't know how many dictionaries are nested inside and becouse of that I don't know what type of object should I cast it to.

I am nesting it through the method:

```
static object budujDrzewo(List<List<string>> data, object decision = null)
{
    if (!warunekStopu())
    {
        object result = null;
        (
            Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>> dictOfChildrenData, 
            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> dictVisualization, 
            string atrIndex
        ) = wyborNajlepszegoPodzialu(data);


        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<List<string>>> children in dictOfChildrenData)
        {                    
            result = budujDrzewo(children.Value, dictVisualization[atrIndex][children.Key]);

            if (result.GetType() == typeof(bool) && (bool)result == false)
            {
                return decision;
            }
            else
            {
                dictVisualization[atrIndex][children.Key] = result;
            }
        }

        return dictVisualization;
    }
    else
    {
        listOfGainRatios.Clear();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Following foreach isn't working:

```
foreach(object obj in tree)
{

}
```

Need help.

Comment: The error clearly tells you what the type of the object is, what type you're trying to cast it to, and that it cannot cast from one type to the other. So what isn't clear?

Comment: In a dictionary where the value type is `object`, then you can use `as` to check for objects that are actually `Dictionary<string, object>`. See duplicate. Of course, in the example you give, it seems that the `tree` object isn't actually a `Dictionary<string, object>`, but rather a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>` in which case casting is pointless. Just enumerate the values in the dictionary directly; you can't treat that object as a `Dictionary<string, object>`, _because it's not one_.

Comment: It tells me to cast it as above, but the type depend on how nested it is. Depending, it could be: {a: {b: {c: {...}}}, it could aswell be {a: {b: c}}, so how to iterate over it?